# How can i create user in salesforce through REST api? Give me some examples

Tags: java, rest, api, salesforce

Am trying to create user into my salesforce account through REST api using java.But its returning 400 status code.Can you please guide me?
Here is the code am trying:

```
 public static void createUsers() {
    System.out.println("\n_______________ USER INSERT _______________");

    String uri = baseUri + "/sobjects/User/";
    System.out.println(uri);
    try {


        //create the JSON object containing the new lead details.
        JSONObject lead = new JSONObject();
        lead.put("FirstName", "Jake");
        lead.put("LastName", "sully");
        lead.put("Alias", "Jake");
        lead.put("Email", "Jake@gmail.com");
        lead.put("Username", "Jake@gmail.com");
        lead.put("Name", "jake");
        lead.put("UserRoleId","00E28000000oD8EEAU");
        lead.put("Id", "10028000000GLSIAA4");
        lead.put("EmailEncodingKey", "ISO-8859-1");
        lead.put("TimeZoneSidKey", "Asia/Kolkata");
        lead.put("LocaleSidKey", "en_US");
        lead.put("ProfileId", "00e280000027hnGAAQ");
        lead.put("LanguageLocaleKey", "en_US");


        //Construct the objects needed for the request
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpPost.addHeader(oauthHeader);
        httpPost.addHeader(prettyPrintHeader);
        // The message we are going to post
        StringEntity body = new StringEntity(lead.toString(1));
        body.setContentType("application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(body);

        //Make the request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        //Process the results
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 201) {
            String response_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response_string);
            // Store the retrieved lead id to use when we update the lead.
            leadId = json.getString("id");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Insertion unsuccessful. Status code returned is " + statusCode);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("Issue creating JSON or processing results");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        npe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't specify Ids of objects you are creating. Those are auto-assigned by Salesforce

Comment: Can you share your log. What was the output of `System.out.println(uri);`